# Kial "mirtelo" kaj ne "blubero"?

Tags: etymology

Eble tio estas stulta demando, sed mi konas la vorton de la sveda *blåbär*, de la germana *Blaubeere* kaj de la angla *blueberry* kaj ili ŝajnas tiom simplaj. "Mirtelo" venas el la franca, mi pensas. Ĉu ie oni povas vidi kial tiu vorto estis elektita?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ne nur la franca sed ankaŭ la itala havas similan formon (*mirtillo*). Mirtelo, kiel multaj plantoj, prenas sian Esperantan nomon de la t.n. “latina nomo” (*Vaccinium myrtillus*).

Comment: Actually, in French it's _myrtille_ and in Italian it's _mirtillo_. The etymology for the Italian word says it comes from the French _myrtille_.

Comment: @kiamlaluno La demando kaj la respondo estas en Esperanto. Via komento — en la angla…

Comment: @LyubomirVasilev there isn't any requirements about the language used for comments. This site is still an English site.

Comment: Ĉu eventuale la persono kiu donis negativan voĉdonon al tiu respondo havas komenton por plibonigi la respondon?

Answer (score 13):

Via demando estas neniel stulta, sed tiaj demandoj ("kial tiu vorto estis elektita") ne havas absolutajn respondojn. Ni ne povas iri en la kapon de la unua uzanto de la vorto, verŝajne Zamenhof mem. Eble li simple prenis la plej Latinecan vorton, el la Franca *myrtille* aŭ el la scienca nomo *Vaccinium myrtillus*, ĉar la alilingvaj nomoj ŝajnis havi nenion komunan. La vorto aperis jam en 1889, se ne pli frue, kaj estas parto de la Universala Vortaro en la Fundamento de Esperanto (1905).

La Sveda vorto por *V. myrtillus* certe estas *blåbär*, sed *blueberry* kaj *Blaubeere* estas nur unu varianto de la nomo en la du aliaj lingvoj (pli kutimaj, mi kredas, estas *bilberry* kaj *Heidelbeere*). Nomojn similajn al "blubero" oni povas en aliaj mondpartoj uzi por aliaj bluaj beroj, ekzemple por la Amerika *Vaccinium corymbosum*, kiu estas kulturata ankaŭ en Eŭropo. Iuj lingvoj nomas la beron ne blua sed nigra (*borówka czarna, черника, mustikka*).

Fakte nenio malhelpas vin uzi vorton kiel "blubero", ekzemple se vi verkas Esperantan fabelon kaj volas doni lokan koloron al la rakonto, sed vi devas scii, ke la komuna kaj tradicia kaj botanika nomo, kiun la legantoj trovas en ĉiu vortaro, estas *mirtelo*. Vi aldonu klarigan noton pri la vorto en via fabelo, aŭ simple lasu la legontojn imagi, kiu mistera bero aŭ planto ĝi estas.

En la [Esperanta indekso de sia *Sveda Floraro*](http://tekstoj.nl/stenjo/sveda_floraro/florespm.html) Sten Johansson donas ĉi tiujn alternativajn nomojn, kiuj aperis en kelkaj vortaroj kaj tekstoj: *vakcinio blua, arbara bero blua, blu-bero*. Sed la normala vorto certe estas *mirtelo*.

Answer (score 4):

Mustikka (Vaccinium myrtillus) estas la finna nomo kaj "musta" estas nigra.
Mi miras kial svedoj kaj finnoj vidas du kolorojn blua kaj nigra je sama bero.
mustelma = blåmärke estas kontuzo = bluaĵo.
Miaj kontuzoj ofte verdas.

Comment: Tio fakte havas interesan historion: Ne-blankuloj estis nomataj "blåmän" en la sveda. Iu iam rakontis al mi ke oni ne faris diferencon inter blua kaj nigra. Ili certe ne estis bluaj, ne temas pri Avatar-uloj!   Cetere, bonvenon al Stack Exchange, Inga!